# How do I test for argument count in RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing, exception, rspec2

How do I test that a given helper method only takes exactly one argument?

I thought of doing this:

```
describe "#textile" do
  it "should take only one argument" do
    textile().should raise_error
  end
end
```

but that seems to still break the test, with the error `wrong number of arguments 0 for 1`.

Comment: Why would you want to test that? In any case, if you test it with a valid, single argument, and change its definition to take more, the test will fail. Unless you give the second argument a default value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of why you'd want to test this, here's one way to write it:

```
describe "#textile" do
  it "should fail when given no arguments" do
    expect { textile() }.to raise_error ArgumentError
  end

  it "should accept one argument" do
    expect { textile("foo") }.not_to raise_error ArgumentError
  end
end
```

Note that you could leave off the `ArgumentError` and just say that these invocations should or should not raise an error, but by specifically saying they should or should not raise ArgumentError, you're isolating the case that you're trying to specify. `textile("foo")` may raise some other kind of exception but will still pass the second example.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can test arity directly.

```
>> method(:hello).arity
=> 2
```

You can get different answers based on those given defaults, plus any `*args` as well.

You will want to [read the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Method.html#method-i-arity) that describes this:

> Returns an indication of the number of arguments accepted by a method.
>   Returns a non-negative integer for methods that take a fixed number of
>   arguments. For Ruby methods that take a variable number of arguments,
>   returns -n-1, where n is the number of required arguments. For methods
>   written in C, returns -1 if the call takes a variable number of
>   arguments.

So, in rspec, you would write your test accordingly, testing arity, rather than testing if it raises errors or not.